Normal $p$-complement exercise (Problem 5D.6 Isaacs' Finite Group Theory)
I have a question about the following problem [Finite Group Theory, Martin Isaacs, Chapter 5]:
Suppose that $P \in Syl_{p}(G)$, and assume that $A \cap P=P^{'}$, where $A=\textbf{A}^{p}(G)$. If $P^{'}$ is abelian, prove (without appealing to Tate's theorem) that $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.
Hint: Let $N=N_{G}(P^{'})$ and observe that $N$ satisfies the hypotheses. Use Burnside's normal p-complement theorem in the group $A$.
I thought I'd use the following two results:
Theorem (Burnside): Let $ P \in Syl_{p}(G) $, where $G$ is a finite group, and suppose $ P \subseteq Z(N_{G}(P)) $. Then $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.
Exercise 5D.1: Let $P \in Syl_{p}(G)$, where $P$ is abelian. Let $P \subseteq H \subseteq G$, and assume that $H$ controls $p$-transfer in $G$. If $H$ has a normal $p$-complement, then $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.
My idea is as follows:
I observe that $P^{'} \in Syl_{p}(A)$. So, if I prove that $P^{'} \subseteq \textbf{Z}(N_{A}(P^{'}))$, then, from the Burnside's theorem, I have to $A$ has a normal $p$-complement. Now, since $P^{'}$ is abelian, $P^{'} \subseteq A \subseteq G$ and $A$ controls $p$-transfer in $G$, for the exercise 5D.1, I have that $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.
Is my reasoning correct? How can it be proven that $P^{'} \subseteq \textbf{Z}(N_{A}(P^{'}))$?

But $P$ is not necessarily abelian, which you need to apply Exercise 5D.1. You should mention that the exercise has a hint.

I added the hint of the book but I didn't quite understand it. $P$ is not abelian but $P^{'}$ is abelian and I applied the Exercise 5D.1 to $P^{'}$.

The hint means that $N$ satisfies the hypotheses of the previous exercise, 5D.5. From that exercise $N$ has a normal $p$-complement which must centralize $P'$, so $P` \le Z(N_A(P'))$.

Oh, now I understand what it meant by "$N$ satisfies the hypotheses" , thank you. Then I have to solve the Exercise 5D.5 to be able to do this.

Yes of course you do! If there are two problems one after the other, and the first is a special case of the second, then the intention must be that you  start by solving the first one.
